# Is it bad practice to have boolean setters to see whether they executed succesfully?

Tags: java

Is it bad practice to write my setters as booleans to check if they were set correctly?

For example, the following code will set whether my frame is always on top and will return true if it is successfully set to what I decided. Is it bad practice to do this, or should I just leave it with no return type?

```
    public boolean setAlwaysOnTop(boolean alwaysOnTop) {
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(alwaysOnTop);
        return frame.isAlwaysOnTop() == alwaysOnTop;
    }
```

Bear in mind in this example I also have a getter for when I want to check the value when not attempting to set it:

```
    public boolean isAlwaysOnTop() {
    return frame.isAlwaysOnTop();
}
```

Thanks in advance. If you would like any more information please feel free to ask and I will provide it.

Edit:

It's just that I was wondering if it would be useful because I could do an

```
if(setAlwaysOnTop(true)) 
do this
```

instead of just using a void like this:

```
  setAlwaysOnTop(true);
  do this
```

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe or are you aware of any situations under which `setAlwaysOnTop` will fail?

Comment: I'm not aware of any reason that it would fail, but this was just an example. It's just an extra check to see if it was successful to ensure no mistakes.

Comment: you can always throw an exception if the setter fails - because of invalid input or something else

Comment: In such a case you can use an `assert` instead of the return value.

Comment: You pass false, and frame.isAlwaysOnTop == false, then it would return true, that is the expected behaviour? `true, if the always-on-top mode is supported by the toolkit and for this window, false, if always-on-top mode is not supported for this window or toolkit doesn't support always-on-top windows.`

Comment: Yes, this is the expected behaviour. It will return true if it sets correctly to the value that you specified.

Comment: Mm i would throw an exception,

Comment: Write a unit test for getters and setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding of additional conditions to check the API work is **not a good idea** in general. **frame.setAlwaysOnTop** must do its work. If you don't trust the API - cover it with unit tests. Only if tests fail you should think about the work around solution - find working version of the software, report a bug or fix the issue if you have access to code base.

Such additional check can make sense only if you know about some existing problem and it can not be fixed now. In this case I would raise custom exception from **setAlwaysOnTop** method (because you know that it is an exceptional case), log the error and perform your sanity actions.

```
public void setAlwaysOnTop(boolean alwaysOnTop) throws UIModificationExcepion {
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(alwaysOnTop);
    // due to existing bug ... is not updated for all cases
    if (frame.isAlwaysOnTop() != alwaysOnTop) {
        throw new UIModificationException("Unable to change 'always on top' property");
    }
}
```

Client code

```
try {
    setAlwaysOnTop(true);
} catch (Exception e) {
    log.warn("Could not update always on top", e);
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear and easy to understand answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to write the code which is required not the extra code(which is bad for maintenance)

```
public boolean setAlwaysOnTop(boolean alwaysOnTop) {
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(alwaysOnTop);
    return frame.isAlwaysOnTop() == alwaysOnTop;
}
```

why do you need to check  `frame.isAlwaysOnTop() == alwaysOnTop;` when you are doing `frame.setAlwaysOnTop(alwaysOnTop);` code will obviuosly set it  To make sure you have written the right code you should write junits but your code should not have anything that you dont require on production but  just to clear your doubts.

so to answer your question yes its a **bad** pracltice